# How can I make nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train() work with my dictionary

Tags: nltk, spam-prevention, naivebayes

I'm currently making a simples spam/ham email filter using Naive Bayles.

For you to understand my algorithm logic: I have a folder with lots os files, which are examples of spam/ham emails. I also have two other files in this folder containing the titles of all my ham examples and another with the titles of all my spam examples. I organized like this so I can open and read this emails properly.

I'm putting all the words I judge to be important in a dictionary structure, with a label "spam" or "ham" depending from which kind of file I extracted them from.

Then I'm using nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train() so I can train my classifier, but I'm getting the error:

*for featureset, label in labeled_featuresets:
ValueError: too many values to unpack*

I don't know why this is happening. When I looked for a solution, I found that strings are not hashable, and I was using a list to do it, then I turned it into a dictionary, which are hashable as far as I know, but it keeps getting this error.
Someone knows how to solve it? Thanks!

All my code is listed below:

```
import nltk
import re 
import random

stopwords   = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')    #Words I should avoid since they have weak value for classification
my_file     = open("spam_files.txt", "r")   #my_file now has the name of each file that contains a spam email example
word        = {}    #a dictionary where I will storage all the words and which value they have (spam or ham)

for lines in my_file:   #for each name of file (which will be represenetd by LINES) of my_file
with open(lines.rsplit('\n')[0]) as email: #I will open the file pointed by LINES, and then, read the email example that is inside this file
    for phrase in email:    #After that, I will take every phrase of this email example I just opened
        try:    #and I'll try to tokenize it
            tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(phrase)
        except: 
            continue    #I will ignore non-ascii elements
        for c in tokens:    #for each token
            regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]') #I will also exclude numbers
            c = regex.sub('', c)
            if (c): #If there is any element left
                if (c not in stopwords): #And if this element is a not a stopword
                    c.lower()
                    word.update({c: 'spam'})#I put this element in my dictionary. Since I'm analysing spam examples, variable C is labeled "spam".

my_file.close() 
email.close()

#The same logic is used for the Ham emails. Since my ham emails contain only ascii elements, I dont test it with TRY
my_file = open("ham_files.txt", "r")
for lines in my_file:
with open(lines.rsplit('\n')[0]) as email:
    for phrase in email:
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(phrase)
        for c in tokens:
            regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
            c = regex.sub('', c)
            if (c):
                if (c not in stopwords):
                    c.lower()
                    word.update({c: 'ham'})

my_file.close() 
email.close()

#And here I train my classifier
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(word)
classifier.show_most_informative_features(5)
```

Comment: besides the problem you describe (and which I addressed below), your code has a number of issues: You shouldn't use the same dict to collect words from both spam and ham emails – rather use a separate bag-of-words dict for every email. Also, `c.lower()` has no effect – you should write `c = c.lower()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train()` expects “*a list of tuples `(featureset, label)`*” (see the documentation of the `train()` method)
What is not mentioned there is that `featureset` should be a dict of feature names mapped to feature values.

So, in a typical spam/ham classification with a bag-of-words model, the labels are 'spam'/'ham' or 1/0 or True/False;
the feature names are the occurring words and the values are the number of times each word occurs.
For example, the argument to the `train()` method might look like this:

```
[({'greetings': 1, 'loan': 2, 'offer': 1}, 'spam'),
 ({'money': 3}, 'spam'),
 ...
 ({'dear': 1, 'meeting': 2}, 'ham'),
 ...
]
```

If your dataset is rather small, you might want to replace the actual word counts with 1, to reduce data sparsity.